# Is there a way to change a path file and automatically refactor code in vim?

Tags: vim, refactoring, vim-plugin, neovim

Is there a way in vim so I can

1. Change the path of a python file
2. Refactor all imports of a python code that uses the changed file

?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the file
2. Open all your python files in vim; e.g., `vim $(find . -iname '*.py')` or `vim $(ack -f --python)`
3. Do the substitute: `argdo %s/import foo.bar/import foo.baz/g`
4. Save and quit

This assumes that all of your imports are absolute (i.e., that none of them are relative).

Comment: is there a plugin that does this automatically, needing just the command to move the file path?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But it should be painfully obvious to script via shell (or other) and not difficult to do via vimscript entirely.